# Any way to avoid getting denied (403) due to sending multiple PHP file_get_contents requests?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403

I have written a WP plug-in that does the following:

On every page load, the plugin retrieves Facebook graph data ( social count ) for the entire blog posts, using `file_get_contents()` and XML feeds. I tested it on a live site that has more than 60 posts, and when I was still doing some tests, I suddenly got my IP blocked and gets denied every time ( 403 ).

My question is, is this going to happen to real users if they install this plug-in and their visitors ? is there such way to avoid getting denied due to many PHP requests?
I also use WP [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache data for an hour.

Regards.

P.S: I tested the plug-in on my localhost and it works fine.

Comment: possibly [rate limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting)?

Comment: Maybe, @castis . rather than retrieving data PHP returns file_get_contents( url here ) + 403 so I suspect that Facebook performs throttling.. I thought caching data will help avoid that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this cool tool:

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls={URLs here separated by commas}
```

which lets me fetch data so fast for 63 URLs that I tested. I don't know if there's a limit, but will definitely read about it.

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix would be to maybe add a small delay if you have to send that many, although you may want to break it up a bit more perhaps ( pagination ).

Just do in your iteration before the execution of your requests ( delay 1/2 a second ) note this could add considerable delays:

```
usleep(500000);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. so basically if I try that, the user should wait 60 * 5 seconds ? Or I got it wrong ?

Comment: You'll probably want to change that number, if there are 60 request you may want to add a modulus count and do the delay every 10 perhaps.  
Alternatively you can work on a good number to delay each one in microseconds.  
Here is a handy converter
http://www.unitconversion.org/time/seconds-to-microseconds-conversion.html

Comment: Apologize, that's not 5 seconds.. Good idea I will give it a try! thanks!!

Comment: Appreciated. have a nice day :)